# Why doesn’t the Gemara say that the Mishnah is like Rabbi Eliezer?

Tags: masechet-taanis

In Taanis 3a, the Gemara brings a Mishnah that says that Nisuch HaMayim is 7 days and then they try to reconcile whose opinion this follows. They say it definitely can’t be Rabbi Akiva or Rabbi Yehuda ben Beteira, so then they do some gymnastics to make it align with Rabbi Yehoshua’s opinion. But the Mishnah is exactly Rabbi Eliezer’s opinion, so why don’t they just say that he’s the Tanna of it? Rashi had a whole thing about how it’s too obvious that Rabbi Eliezer believes this so we need to attribute it to a different Tanna, but since when is this a Gemara answer, that something is obviously the view of one guy so he must not be the writer of it? Why is the Gemara not just sticking with the simple answer?

Comment: Tosfos argues with rashi and holds that according to R’ Eliezer nisuch hamayim is only on the second day

Comment: @Chatzkel but then why would he hold that we start saying Mashiv Haruach on the first day if it lines up with Nisuch HaMayim? I was initially thinking that I know on the previous Daf there was a discussion of whether mashiv haruach is because of lulav or nisuch mayim so maybe Eliezer holds it’s because of lulav and therefore saying mashiv has no relevance to how long Nisuch HaMayim is done for. But I didn’t see any commentaries saying this

Comment: Tosfos over there says exactly that

Comment: @Chatzkel oh lol so maybe I read it wrong. What was the conclusion though of the discussion on 2b about whether mashiv is because of lulav or nisuch? Don’t have the text in front of me now but I do remember the conclusion being lulav so even this whole discussion of matching the different opinions with Nisuch was perplexing and unnecessary

Comment: דאמר רבי אבהו לא למדה רבי אליעזר אלא מלולב. פירוש וסבירא ליה דניסוך לא הוי עד בשני:
That’s what Tosfos says there